# Remove Text from String & Keep Leading Number

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way to remove a text string from cells that contain a leading number since all I need is the number in order to use it in a pivot table.

Here's an example of the data.

```
5 or more times
1 time
3 times
2 times
```

This data is found in column "BI" and it's stored in a worksheet called "DB".

I have a Macro to remove the time from a date/time formatted column and if I could run both one after the other, that'd be great.

Here's the code to remove time from date/time.

```
Sub ToDate()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long

Sheets("DB").Select

LR = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    With Range("N" & i)
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyy"
        .Value = DateValue(.Value)
    End With
Next i

Sheets("Tasks").Select
GoTo Fin:

Fin:
MsgBox ("Process Completed")

End Sub
```

Comment: You can get the code for the same here: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1622-excel-extract-number-from-string.html

Comment: Is the number always preceding the string and is it always separated by a space?

Comment: Thank you Paresh. I tried that sample code and it brings up a popup box to choose the range and I need the code to execute without additional interaction. I don't know how to edit that sample to make it work that way on a particular sheet and range (BI column).

Comment: D_Zab, Yes the contents of that column always beging with a leading number followed by a text straing like in the example I posted.

Comment: You could use the `Val` function which ignores leading spaces and  trailing text so `.Value = Val(.Value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is always a space after the number use

```
' Check that cell has a value
if .Value <> "" Then   
    .Value = Left(.Value,Instr(.Value," ")-1)
Endif
```

Use -1 to remove space

Comment: add -1 to remove space

Comment: Thank you Paul Kelly and Chrismas007. It works but there's just one issue. At some point in the "BI" Range, there could (there are) empty cells before the data continues and the macro halts with an error once it finds the first empty cell. Unfortunately, those empty cells cannot be removed since there is additional data in the same row that I need to keep. This is how I did it. LR = Range("BI" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    With Range("BI" & i)
        .Value = Left(.Value, InStr(.Value, " ") - 1)
    End With
Next i

Comment: You can check that cell is not blank before trying to change it. I've updated the code in the example.

Comment: Now I get an error. The debug points to .Value = Left(.Value,Instr(.Value," ")-1) and the error is "Invalid Procedure call or Argument". This is how I formatted the code. For i = 2 To LR
    With Range("BI" & i)
        If .Value <> "" Then
        .Value = Left(.Value, InStr(.Value, " ") - 1)
        End If
    End With
Next i

Comment: Btw, .Value = Left(.Value,Instr(.Value," ")-1) if I remove the space from " " the code runs but it just deletes everything from the column.

Comment: Ah! I I got it to work. I removed the -1 from the code line and it removed the space from " " now it removes all text and leaves the leading numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This will return everything at the beginning of the string until a space character.  The reason the `- 1` is important is that you don't want the space character in your final result.

```
With Range("BI" & i)
    .Value = Left(.Value, InStr(.Value, " ") - 1)
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also work:

```
if .Value <> "" Then   
    .Value = Split(.Value, " ")(0)
Endif
```

Comment: Thank you. Already got it to work =). Also tried your approach and it works too.